# What security measures should I take before I finish migrating from mysql_ to PDO?

Tags: php, mysql

I have been working on this project for 7 years. Now dozens of people use this software every day in their work.

When I was beginning (with PHP 5.2.X), I didn't know that `mysql_` would be deprecated, so I was using it freely. Now I am running PHP 5.4.4 and I feel the urgency of upgrading, but I have thousands of `mysql_query` calls in my code. It will take ages to migrate to `PDO`, but **I know it must be finally done**.

From the get-go I have been sanitizing user input going through each post, get, cookie, request array recursively like this:

```
$_POST = array_map_recursive('stripslashes', $_POST);
$_POST = array_map_recursive('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST);
```

I prepend the file with this code with `.htaccess`, so each php file has it prepended. **I know it is wrong**, but I started coding knowing nothing about good practices and had never any reason/time to change that.

I also hold in array all (thousands) name/value pairs of inputs like select, radio, checkbox and I filter them every time.

**Question**: before I will be done changing each `mysql_` function to `PDO`, what is the possible threat of mysql injection or any other mailicious attack on my code resulting from my *above mentioned* obsolete combination of `mysql_` and global sanitization? Do you have any advice for this temporary solution for developers maintaining obsolete code with thousands of mysql_queries?

Comment: You can take out that `stripslashes`, there's no value in it - `mysql_real_escape_string` would have been fine on its own. Once you are on PDO you don't need either, as long as you are binding using placeholders and `prepare()`. If you have thousands of calls to this library directly, you are discovering the value of having a wrapper class to protect you against large numbers of changes!

Comment: I hold it because the $POST values may cascade down to included files because there is auto prepend and then they are acquiring new and new slashes. It came out of my practice, I was trying everything.

Comment: What do you mean by "they are acquiring new and new slashes"? Are you using the magic quotes feature?

Comment: This is why we use custom Classes. Update the functions in your custom class and it updates it everywhere that function is used. I'd definitely look into this if you're already overhauling the project.

Comment: There has been a note on the mysql extantions pages since 2007 stating that they were outdated and would be deprecated at some future date, so use mysqli/pdo instead. 2007. If people read the manual more they would not end up in this state.

Comment: Sounds like you have a very fractured code base with bad data sanitization practices and no centralized DB interaction code.  It is really going to be a mess to fix.  You probably first need to refactor the code you do have before trying to migrate to PDO.  That being said, this is too broad a question for SO.

Comment: I know I screwed up, I created db class, but too late. I know how I should change it, but I ask for one example of successful attack. Just one example, it is not too broad.

Comment: If you swap all your calls to use parameter binding, no injection attack can get through (as far as is known). So, no example is possible. If you want a general example of SQL injection, remove your two escaping lines, and then use a string containing an apostrophe - that will break it for sure.

Comment: @halfer I know how injection looks and that is probably impossible with prepared statements. But I'd like too see example of attack on my current code as is. If it is impossible, then I think I don't need to migrate unless I use php version with mysq_ removed. If it is impossible, it would mean that there is a way to prevent injection.

Comment: It's hard to say what might constitute a successful attack in your specific case. There are some automated tools to make some attempts, or you could present your code to a security company for them to analyse. However you really should switch to prepared/bound statements, even if you are sure (or as sure as it is possible to be) that your app is secure in its present state.

Answer (score 1):

You're really in a pretty mess there. Your reliance on global escaping means all your values are being mangled as they come into your app. They're not the original values the user supplied anymore, they will have sprouted random new backslashes. However, as we all know, it's a terrible idea to do that, you should be using parameterised queries and bind your values.

Now here's your predicament: if you *remove* the global escaping and switch to binding values, all your mysql calls which relied on global escaping will be vulnerable to SQL injection. If you just leave in the global escaping and are additionally binding your data, it will contain random additional backslashes. `stripslashes` *may* remove them cleanly, or it may not. It's not designed to un-mysqlescape a string. Your only real way out of this mess is to replace all mysql function calls with prepared statements in one go; migrating little by little is almost impossible.

Comment: ... and the OP can run their unit/functional test suite to make sure everything is OK.

Comment: thanks for insight, I am aware of all that, but before I change everything, I would like to see one example of malicious input that would be successful. Before I see it I cannot see a reason for change unless I upgrade to php version that has mysql_ removed.

Comment: @n-dru There's no vulnerability as such in your current code. mysql properly applied is as secure as anything else. The point is, you'll have to discontinue your old ways in order to switch to the new ways. During that transition, your app *may* be vulnerable (to any standard SQL injection, no examples necessary).

Comment: I am sorry if I impose on you with my thoughts, but if it is safe, I could wait til mysql_ is removed and then define my own function mysql_query inside of which I will just call pdo queriy, without prepared statements - I think that if it is possible, it might be my plan B instead of taking risk of creating bugs during rewriting.

Comment: @n-dru: the correct way to do it is to write a suite of automated functional tests that checks every part of your app. You can then do the PDO upgrade with confidence. You won't be able to just replace `mysql_query` with your own function anyway, since you need to prepare/execute - two separate calls.

Comment: @n-dru Maybe you'll be able to write a drop-in replacement function, yes (you'll also have to do so for `mysql_real_escape_string` and any other mysql functions you use). That sounds like terrible code, but then there really isn't an easy and elegant solution out of this corner you've painted yourself into.